# invalid value being printed in angular foreach

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using the code below to loop through all the objects, to see if each object is valid:

```js
angular.forEach(formName, function (value, key) {
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    if (value.$error.required === true || value.$$success.required === true) {
      console.log(value.$name);
      console.log(value.$valid);
      console.log(value);
    }
  }
});
```

When I look at the object Value in the console, I see that $valid = true, however when I'm printing value.$valid it prints false. When I try to print value.$$success.required it prints undefined instead of true.

Comment: _"When I look at the object Value in the console, I see that $valid = true, however when I'm printing value.$valid it prints false"_ That's not a contradiction and it's a symptom. What's the actual problem?

Comment: The issue is that if you look at the object, $valid is true, however when trying to use it, in this case using console.log(value.$valid) it prints false. I expected them both to be true.

Comment: It's a timing issue. It depends on when you look at the object and when you print the value. Provided you actually have the same object in both situations. The question still is: how does that affect the application? Or do you just want to know the reason for that behavior?

Comment: I looked at the timing issue, even if I swap the lines around, so it prints the value first in the console, it still says value.$valid = false. We need this, so we can build a list of all the valid objects on the form.

Comment: The timing issue is not about printing the values, but about you inspecting the value in the console. Objects in the console update when you inspect them. They don't show the state at the time they were printed. That's why I asked _"What's the actual problem?"_. The problem is not different values. Maybe you call the code from your question too early. Unfortunately you have provided no context.